# JAVA EE - id tag are not parsed in orm.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm a newbie in JPA world, and I try to don't work with annotations, (just with XML file (orm.xml) ), so I follow this tutorial [of mapping in JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html), 
suddenly spring boot can't create a bean with name it entityManagerFactory   , because the entity Formation doesn't have an identifier, but the problem is in the orm.xml file, I define the tag id with the same name of property in Formation class, [this a link to project](https://github.com/ekkatharisi/error) , and this is the entities of the project :

Etudiant :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Etudiant implements  Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Formation formation;
}
```

Formation :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Formation implements  Serializable {
    //@Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private int duree;
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy="formation", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Etudiant> etudiants;
}
```

and this is the orm.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings>
    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Formation">
        <table name="formations">
            <attributes>
                <id name="id">
                    <genrated-value strategy="AUTO"></genrated-value>
                </id>
                <basic name="nom"></basic>
                <basic name="duree"></basic>
                <one-to-many mappedby="formation" fetch="lazy">
                    <basic name="etudiants"></basic>
                </one-to-many>
            </attributes>
        </table>
    </entity>
    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Etudiant">
        <table name="etudiants">
            <attributes>
                <id name="id">
                    <genrated-value strategy="AUTO"></genrated-value>
                </id>
                <basic name="nom"></basic>
                <basic name="prenom"></basic>
                <many-to-one>
                    <Join-column name="id_formation">
                        <basic name="formation"></basic>
                    </Join-column>
                </many-to-one>
            </attributes>
        </table>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

and this is the exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: org.sid.dao.entity.Formation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.sid.ApplicationSyntheseApplication.main(ApplicationSyntheseApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: org.sid.dao.entity.Formation
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:717) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

the problem is that i'm sure that the orm.xml ,file is has been loaded in build.
:

Answer (score 1):

Your `orm.xml` is invalid. The `attributes` tag should be outside the `table` tag. I suggest adding the following header to your `orm.xml`.

```
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
```

Then open your `orm.xml` in a decent IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse should do the trick) and fix all the validation errors in your `orm.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Formation" access="FIELD">
        <table name="formations" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <basic name="nom" />
            <basic name="duree" />
            <one-to-many name="etudiants" mapped-by="formation" fetch="LAZY" />
        </attributes>
    </entity>
    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Etudiant" access="FIELD">
        <table name="etudiants" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <basic name="nom"/>
            <basic name="prenom"/>
            <many-to-one name="formation">
                <join-column name="id_formation" />
            </many-to-one>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

It should look something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception using the `orm.xml`. Adding a getter and setter for the `id` field solved the issue.

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Looks like you have typo in your xml — `genrated-value` instead of `generated-value`
2. For spring boot to work with orm.xml files you should say EntityManagerFactory to use it. i.e. if your JPA provider is Hibernate:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class HibernateConfiguration extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration {
       @Bean
       @Override
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
               EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder)
       {
           final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ret = super.entityManagerFactory(factoryBuilder);
           ret.setMappingResources("orm.xml");
           return ret;
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: thank you for responding me, but I have the same error, now can you tell me any dependencies I can include it in the project to use the configuration class? and are there another method to do it like another XML file ??

Comment: where is your orm.xml located?

Comment: @ekka looks like it should be in src/main/resources/META-INF

Comment: yes i'm sorry it is in /src/main/resouces/META-INF : now i'm getting a new error :Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : orm.xml : origin(orm.xml)

Comment: You don't need to use `setMappingResources` if the `orm.xml` is in the default location. Also advicing to extend the auto configuration is something you shouldn't be doing.